# Evaluation and Presentation of cloud masked satellite images from Earth Engine for a report

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel

I'm facing the problem that I lack ideas on how to quantitatively evaluate the cloud masking I have proceeded with the satellite image in Earth Engine.

What would be a common approach? What charts are suitable for the evaluation?

I tried to create charts and accessing the properties 'CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE' and 'CLOUD_COVER_ASSESSMENT' of the Sentinel-2 L1 ImageCollection.